# useContext returns undefined in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning `hooks` and trying to understand `useContext`. The component is a child of the `provider`,

But when I  see the **`value`** returned by `useContext`, it is **undefined**.

https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-star-2mz87?file=/src/C2.js

**In the component C2, I get undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use named import in c2:

```
import {CContext} from "./App";
```

instead  of default import which will give you `App` react component `import CContext from "./App";`